# Why does my VS Code Live Server Extention show images when open on browser but images don't show when opening it with index.html file

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, browser, liveserver

So here is the issue I use VS Code and the live server exstention. but now when I open the website with Go Live in VS Code then the images i have inserted in the website displays perfectly as the should whut then when I open the website on the index.html file then I only het the alt text thats but in the html and the images dont display.

I have doulble and triple checked the paths and I also have moved the images to a new folder and changed the name and then changed all the sources in the HTML code but it did not change anything at all, I also tried using different browsers (Chrome, firefox, microsoft edge) did not find anything

```html
<img
   class="section-main--img1"
  src="/img/3 items.png"
  alt="Picture of all 3 colors"
/>
<img
  class="section-main--img2"
  src="/img/all 3.png"
  alt="Picture of all 3 items"
/>
```

```css
.section-main--img1 {
  width: 70%;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  justify-self: center;
}

.section-main--img2 {
  width: 60%;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

I have more images in my project but all of them are done in the exact same way.

Can someone help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on how relative URLs are resolved. They are relative to the URL of the HTML document. If you change the URL of the HTML document then the relative URL will resolve differently.

If you open `http://localhost/index.html` then `/img/3 items.png` is going to resolve to `http://localhost/img/3 items.png`

If you open `file:///c/users/me/mywebsite/index.html` then `/img/3 items.png` is going to resolve to `file:///c/img/3 items.png` … which is the wrong path.

Comment: Oh yes I see what you mean, they are in the correct place as I said when I open with the Live server extention it all works but when its done from file explorer with index.html then the images dont show

Comment: Well, yes, obviously. Don't load websites from file systems. Use an HTTP server.

Comment: Will it the still work fine when publishing the website?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using "/" before the folder name. If you have a folder name "A" and here you have your HTML file and you have a subfolder of "A", named "B" in which you have the image then instead of writing a path like "/B/image.xyz" write"B/image.xyz"

```html
<img
   class="section-main--img1"
  src="/img/3 items.png"
  alt="Picture of all 3 colors"
/>
<img
  class="section-main--img2"
  src="img/all 3.png"
  alt="Picture of all 3 items"
/>
```